# Cannot invoke webservice method in Jersey/java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have made a barebones hello world webservice using netbeans and jersey.
My problem is when I deploy my webservice to the server (I'm using glass fish) It takes me to the index page, but I cannot invoke the method I created in the java class.

The domain my glass fish service is using is

`http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp/`

To invoke my method (from what ive read) this is the way to do it:

`http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp/helloworld`

However this gives me a 404. Ive followed many examples but cant seem to invoke the method in my web browser.

I can however invoke the method when I click test RESTful Webservices in netbeans.

Here is how I Defined the Method:

```
 package HelloWorldResource;

 import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
 import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class Hellworld {

@Context
private UriInfo context;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of Hellworld
 */
public Hellworld() {
}

/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of HelloWorldResource.Hellworld
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getHtml() {
    //TODO return proper representation object
    return "<HTML>Hello</HTML>";
}

/**
 * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of Hellworld
 * @param content representation for the resource
 */
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void putHtml(String content) {
}
```

Comment: Do you have some other configuration? Just a resource class is not enough. You either need web.xml configuration or Java configuration. If you don't have any configuration, have a look at [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet)

Comment: Hmm I followed this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghmsj/  apparently netbeans sets all that web.xml stuff for me? I could be wrong but it didn't go over that file in the guide

Comment: That's not a very good tutorial. It doesn't mention anything about configuration, which is required. If one of the steps to create the app, doesn't result in either a web.xml (with required Jersey configuration) or a JAX-RS Application subclass being created, then you will need to add this yourself. Maybe look for a better tutorial.

Comment: Actually apparently web.xml is not needed. I couldn't find it in my project but I looked up another tutorial and found some information. Theres a java class that's created called "ApplicationConfig.java" that has this tag: @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")   so I had to invoke the method using this uri `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp/webresources/helloworld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up another tutorial and found some information. Theres a java class that's created called "ApplicationConfig.java" that has this tag: `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")`

so I had to invoke the method using this uri `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApp/webresources/helloworld`

Answer (score 0):

Please share you web.xml and resource config implementation. If you have any custom resource config implementation, then your resource file has to be registered in the resource config implementation. For details please refer http://cloudskol.com/index.php/2015/09/22/simple-get-method-implementation-in-restful-java/